# I have child Fragment2 inside parent fragment1 and I want change fragment on back click and next time on Back Pressed I want close the activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

For change child fragment2(container inside fragment 1 parent fragment)

```
       view.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    view.requestFocus()
    view.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            childFragmentManager!!.popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)

            return@OnKeyListener true
        }

        false
    })
```

For close the activity

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed()
            finishAffinity()
        return
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitOnce = true

    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Press again to exit ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    Handler().postDelayed({
        kotlin.run { doubleBackToExitOnce = false }
    }, 2000)
}
```

In this case I only able to change child fragment and not able to close the activity

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity()
                    .getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container)).commit();
```

also you can remove fragment by TAG

Comment: On activity I have parent fragment and Inside it i have two child fragment and on back press child fragment replace but i m not able close the activity .